# Trim text from scraped element - Python / bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using `soup.find('div', class_='listing-agent').get_text()` to get the result `Listed by Joe Smith • ACME CO`. I'm trying to just get `Joe Smith`. How can I trim up text to just get a name?

```
<div class="listing-agent">
  <span>
    "Listed by "
    <span>Joe Smith</span>
    <span>
    <span class="font-dot">•</span>
    <!-- -->
    "ACME CO"
    <!-- -->
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try it:

```
n = soup.find('div', class_='listing-agent')

name = n.find_all('span')[1].text

print(name)
```

Output will be: `Joe Smith`

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Let:

```
a = soup.find('div', class_='listing-agent')

name = a.find_all('span')[0].find_all('span')[0].text # parsing the span
```

This gives:

```
>>>name
Joe Smith
```